# Sending 100k+ requests/s with WebClient?

Tags: .net, multithreading, http, asynchronous, webclient

I have written a simple http client in .Net that needs to issue 100k (or thereabouts) http requests per second to stress test a web service. The web service is running on the same machine as the client.

I seem to have hit a wall at 20k requests/s on a 4 core development machine. CPU usage is only at 50%.

Furthermore, it doesn't seem to scale well - I'm only getting 50k requests per second on a 12core server at 25% CPU. The server is roughly 5x more performant in GFlops than the dev machine.

In both cases, the server service is running at about 1/3rd of the CPU usage of the client issuing the requests, so it seems that I'm only stress testing the client...

I have tried running tight loops on multiple threads, using async requests (though I'm not sure I've used these correctly). If I raise the number of threads too high, performance actually drops, presumably due to context switching.

Is there a pattern to follow to reach my performance target? Or am I simply not going to reach it using WebClient?

*Note: The code below is not complete and will not compile, I omitted a lot of stuff for clarity*

```
Class MainWindow

    Public Sub Init() Handles MyBase.Loaded

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 1000
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = False

        ApiInterface.HostDomain = Me.HostDomain
        ApiInterface.Authenticate("SomeUsername", "Password")

        For i As Integer = 1 To Environment.ProcessorCount * 4

            Dim Thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ApiInterface.RandomApiCall)
            Thread.Start()

        Next

    End Sub

End Class




Public Class ApiCalls


    Public ApiCalls As New List(Of ApiCallDelegate)


    Public Sub New()

        ApiCalls.Add(AddressOf Me.ForumRequest)
        ApiCalls.Add(AddressOf Me.SessionListRequest)
        ApiCalls.Add(AddressOf Me.MemberSearchRequest)
        ApiCalls.Add(AddressOf Me.ChatRequest)

    End Sub


    Public Delegate Sub ApiCallDelegate()


    Public Sub MemberSearchRequest()

        Dim Request As New Api.Search.MemberSearchRequest
        Request.StartAt = ThreadSafeRandom.Next(0, 999)
        Request.Auth = Me.Auth
        Request.Count = ThreadSafeRandom.Next(0, 100)
        Request.Country = Countries.GetRandomCountryCode

        ApiCall(Me.HostDomain & "/api/search/members", Request)

    End Sub



    Private Sub ApiCall(Uri As String, Data As Object)

        Dim Client As New WebClient
        AddHandler Client.UploadStringCompleted, AddressOf OnRequestComplete
        Client.UploadStringAsync(New System.Uri(Uri), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data))

    End Sub



    Public Sub OnRequestComplete(Sender As Object, Args As UploadStringCompletedEventArgs)

        If Args.Error Is Nothing Then

            Interlocked.Increment(Status200Count)

        Else

            Select Case CType(CType(Args.Error, WebException).Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode

                Case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                    Interlocked.Increment(Status500Count)

                Case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                    Interlocked.Increment(Status400Count)

                Case HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
                    Interlocked.Increment(Status401Count)

                Case Else
                    Interlocked.Increment(StatusOtherCount)

            End Select

        End If

        If Not Me.Stopping Then RandomApiCall()

    End Sub


    Public Sub RandomApiCall()

        Me.ApiCalls(Rand.Next(0, Me.ApiCalls.Count)).Invoke()

    End Sub



End Class
```

Comment: Why are you not using multiple clients?

Comment: @MareInfinitus: He is

Comment: @Satellite: Increase the number of connections to 10000. I doubt that VB will squeeze 10k/s on a single connection.

Comment: How fast is your lan?

Comment: On multiple client machines you mean? Network latency... Even with a few ms latency introduced I'd need many more machines than are available during development to reach the requests/s count that I'm getting now on a single box. Will definitely spin up a bunch of machines in the cloud for this purpose when development is further advanced, it's just not practical to have them spun up all the time for development though.

Comment: @jgauffin: Did you mean the connection counts specified in ServicePointManager? I just upped this to 10k with no improvement. LAN is not involved, as per the question the client is running on the same box as the web service to minimize latency and maximize throughput.

Comment: What HTTP server are you using?

Comment: The server is a self-hosted .Net service using HttpListener